# Laravel instead using Session in Controller and web.php

Tags: php, laravel, session-variables

We have a restaurant page where the user can add his zip and we're showing the restaurants. We have solved this like this:
web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'restaurants', 'namespace' => 'frontEnd', 'middleware'=>'checkzipcode'], function () {
            Route::get('/', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants');
            Route::post('/', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants');
            Route::get('search','RestaurantController@searchRestaurant');
            Route::post('typefilter','RestaurantController@productTypeFilter');
```

RestaurantController.php

```
public function showAllRestaurants(Request $request)
    {
        $getZipCode = session::get('zipcode',$request->zip_code);

        if(!empty($getZipCode))
        {

            if(Auth::check()) {
                $country_code = Auth::user()->country_code;
            } else {
                $country_code = Common::GetIPData()->iso_code;
            }

            // get all restaurant using zipcode
            $all_restaurant = Restaurant::leftJoin('restaurant_delivery_areas','restaurant_delivery_areas.restaurant_id','=','restaurants.id')
                            ->leftJoin('zip_codes','zip_codes.id','=','restaurant_delivery_areas.zip_code_id')
                            ->leftJoin('restaurant_cuisines','restaurant_cuisines.restaurant_id','=','restaurants.id')
                            ->where('restaurants.country_code',$country_code)
                            ->where(function ($q) use($getZipCode) {
                                $q->where('restaurants.zip',$getZipCode)
                                ->orWhere('zip_codes.postal_code',$getZipCode)
                                ->where('restaurant_delivery_areas.is_active','=',1);
                            });
```

So now we would like to have just for each zip which is db a page like: test.com/restaurants/zip

Does anybody have a suggetion?

Comment: Comprendo? Nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure if i understood your question. But it seems to me that you just want to pass the zipcode as a url parameter, and not in the GET query.

If that's true, you could just receive the zip as the second parameter for the showAllRestaurants() method like this :

```
public function showAllRestaurants(Request $request, $zip_code){
    //...
}
```

Now, the zip_code is received on the $zip_code variable, inside your method.

And change the web.php to support that.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'restaurants', 'namespace' => 'frontEnd', 'middleware'=>'checkzipcode'], function () {
        Route::get('/{zip_code}', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants');
        Route::post('/{zip_code}', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants');
        Route::get('search','RestaurantController@searchRestaurant');
        Route::post('typefilter','RestaurantController@productTypeFilter');
```

To avoid conflits in this case of routing you should use some regex expression to tell laravel what a `zip_code` is, otherwise if you say /restaurants/search, it will think that the 'search' word is a zip_code.

In  the case your zip_code has just numbers. You could add the where() clause on the routes like the following.

```
 Route::get('/{zip_code}', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants')->where('zip_code', '[0-9]+');
 Route::post('/{zip_code}', 'RestaurantController@showAllRestaurants')->where('zip_code', '[0-9]+');
```

If your zip_code contains other characters you should google for (or make one yourself) some regex that fit your zip_code format.

Hope that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, we have solved the problem with your help.